# Error while accessing ADB2C Forgot password link in SignIn page

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

We have integrate ADB2C with a java web application, once user click on Signin button user navigated to the Signin page, while accessing the Forgot password link in Signin page user unable to redirect to forgot password page and b2c issuing this error code “AADB2C90118”. I’ve found that this is a bug in B2C. Please suggest us if this bug is already fixed in ADB2C. Else, please suggest an approach to handle this forgot password error from the java web application standpoint. I really appreciate your time in reading this and sharing your thoughts. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.

This is by design.

This flow is now deprecated. You can find a more modern flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this update. As per the steps provided in this document, updated the B2C forgot policy successfully. But, once a forgot password flow is completed, user directly auto logged in to the application, as per our requirement user must be redirect to the Home Screen with forgot password success response, then user must click on the SignIn button to login to the application. To achieve this requirement with the given document reference, is there any additional step to configure to prevent the user from auto login to application upon successful forgot password completion.

Comment: Else, is there any reference to handle it from the ‘HTML by changing the forgot password ‘link reference’, where it will call the b2c forgot password user flow endpoint directly, user upon clicking the forgot password link in SignIn page. With this approach hoping that B2C won’t send any error code to the application, instead it will loads the forgot password page to the user.   

Thank you for considering this and valuable response.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-reset-only

Comment: Hi there. I’ve implemented the given approach in B2C based on the “Self-service Password Reset” document. While testing the user login flow, unfortunately this user navigated to a forgot password instead of login to our application. But, actual forgot password flow is working fine. During login flow it looks like the policies are overlapping the flow.  Please suggest me if there anything i can modify in B2C side. Followed this document to modify the signin and forgot password policy https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Check your code against this - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset